# Oracle ATG E-Commerce is Open Source or Commerical?

Tags: oracle

I went through the net but couldn't clearly find out the following details.

1. Is Oracle ATG e-commerce is Open Source or Commercial?
2. Does it supports MySQL database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Oracle ATG Commerce (now only known as Oracle Commerce) is a commercial software. Please note that release 11.3 was the last planned release of the product and Oracle will start phasing it out after that. Oracle is now promoting the cloud version of this product known simply as Oracle Commerce Cloud.

Yes, MySQL is supported by Oracle Commerce.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle ATG is a commercial software. For development purposes you can use it for free having downloads from https://edelivery.oracle.com/

It does support mysql database and it comes as a package (included along with installation). But Oracle highly recommends not to use it for production purposes. Oracle, MSSQL or DB2 are suggested for production.

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE ATG is an enterprise Ecommerce commercial solution. Yes, various back-end databases are supported in ATG including MySQL.